# python: ImportError: cannot import name MRjob

Tags: python, canopy, mrjob

In Canopy editor , while executing "from mrjob.job import MRjob" i am getting "ImportError: cannot import name MRjob" , not sure, whats wrong here.

Anybody please suggest. Thanks much in advance

Thanks & Regards,
DP

Answer (score 0):

The "j" in `MRjob` should be capitalized.

Try `from mrjob.job import MRJob`

Comment: It totally answers the question. The poster has a error. The poster's "j" in `MRjob` is lower-case; it should be upper-case.